# Angular ui-router nesting views flashes undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a main view defined, and within that main view, I define an abstract template for my blog posts. The blog has two views associated with it: "list" and "sidebar". There are two states that use this abstraction, one where the "list" is the list of blog posts (with their content truncated), and one where the "list" is a single blog post. The sidebar just contains links to recent blogs and popular tags and only exists in these two mentioned views. Here is how my routes are defined:

```
$stateProvider.state('blog', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "partials/blog.html",
    controller: "BlogController"
}).state('blog.home', {
    url: "/blog",

    views: {
        list : {
            templateUrl: "partials/blog-list.html",
            controller: "BlogPostController"
        },
        sidebar: {
            templateUrl: "partials/blog-sidebar.html",
            controller: "BlogPostController"
        }
    },
    resolve: {

    }
}).state("blog.view", {
    url: "/blog/:blogSlug",

    views: {
        list : {
            templateUrl: "partials/blog-post.html",
            controller: "BlogPostController"
        },
        sidebar: {
            templateUrl: "partials/blog-sidebar.html",
            controller: "BlogPostController"
        }
    }

})
```

Then in my blog view I have:

```
<div ui-view="list"></div>
<div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
```

Everything seems to be working fine, except within my "list" view, when I switch between "blog.home" to "blog.view" (from viewing the list to viewing the single blog post), it flashes "undefined". There are also errors that show up in the console, so it looks like it tries to render that template, but there is no information, and then refreshes with the information.

I read a little bit about resolve, but I don't see how I can pass the information to the child view since the information is not known yet. I also tried to used the ng-cloak attribute which has been suggested, but it didn't work and I was told the ui-router doesn't respond to ng-cloak.

Am I approaching this problem incorrectly or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/uOo1CSKSPEpNNYP9Ht3b?p=preview

Use `resolve` if you would like to wait for a promise, before your controller is invoked.

```
  $stateProvider.state("post", {
    template: "<h1>{{ post.title }}</h1><div>{{ post.content }}</div>",
    url: "/post/:id",
    resolve: {
      blog: function($stateParams, $http, $timeout) {
        var postid = $stateParams.id;
        console.log("Fetching blog post: " + postid);
        var promise = $http.get('blog.json').then(function (response) {
          // simulate long delay using $timeout before returning the blog posts
          return $timeout(function() { return response.data[postid]; }, 2000);              
        });

        return promise;
      }
    },
    controller: function($scope, blog) {
      $scope.post = blog;
      console.log("Controller invoked.  Blog post: ", $scope.post);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I tried some variety of resolve before but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit far from UIRouter at this time...

Been working on my own site written in Angular witch among other things will contain a blog module... While I am only in the very initial stage of trying to push the core implementation out into the Open Source world, maybe you can obtain some inspiration from it...

This uses: https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-routing instead, which is very similar in many ways...

Anyways, here is the initial core of the blog module:

https://github.com/dotJEM/Blog/blob/master/src/client/modules/blog/scripts/blog.ts

The basic consensus is that You might actually not need the "Sidebar" view, instead I have a 'root' view which when on the blog page gets populated by the 'blog.html' template that then just contains the sidebar and has a 'content' view to push in either a list of entries or a single entry depending on what state is active.

Comment: Ah yes that's a good idea... That doesn't solve my issue but that makes my code better :)